# Automatic tableview cell height for only one type of prototype cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview that has multiple prototype cells that it displays. I only want to enable one of these prototype cells to adjust it's height depending on the length of a user's comment.

Is this possible? I use the two lines below for a tableview with only one cell prototype to make it adjustable, but how to do this for only one prototype when several prototype cells exist? Any insights are greatly appreciated!

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, may be I am not understood correctly. But, in my mind it is better use:

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // here you can put you code for any manipulations..
    CGFloat height = 60.f;
    return height;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am already using `heightForRow:` for the cells that will always be the same size. For my one prototype cell for user comments, I need this one prototype only to be able to adjust to the size of the comment. None of the other cell prototypes need to adjust size.

Comment: In `heightForRow:` all I need to do is `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the proper row. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, very simple. In `heightForRow:` check which `indexPath.row` is being loaded (if you have cells that will be in the same index path every time, except for comments). Then in that index path, the height should `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.